# SAPUI5 timeseries_stacked_column chart displaying empty weeks even though there's no data

Tags: sapui5

I'm creating the timeseries_stacked_column chart using SAPUI5 and the framework is plotting data for missing weeks even thought it's not fed to the chart. Please can anyone guide what's the best approach to avoid this.

**Document link for chart property reference:**
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Bar%20%20(15)/Stacked%20Column%20Chart%20for%20Date/Time%20Series/

**Please see the screenshot below for the issue**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the time series doesn't skip the intervals so the alternate solution to this was to use stacked_column chart with array of dimensions ["Year", "Week"] and plot accordingly.

```
Example: https://jsbin.com/nejefizuve/edit?html,output
```